# Need a solution so when I press Enter, turtle draws a different shape

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The code I am trying to write needs to make 5 different shapes, which only one is included.   I am not worried about coding the other 4.

What I need to know is how do I set it up so every time I press enter, turtle will perform a different function based on how many times the key is pressed?

This is the code I currently have, again very unfinished code.

```
import turtle

def draw_triangle():
turtle.color('black')
draw_line_turn()
draw_line_turn()
draw_line_turn()
def draw_line_turn():
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(30)
turtle.left(120)
turtle.up()
def triangle_sequence1():
turtle.clear()
draw_triangle()
def draw_ts1():
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(triangle_sequence1, "Return")


draw_ts1()
turtle.done()
```

Pretty much, ts1 is the first of 5 shapes that need to be drawn by pressing only the Enter key.  I think I need to make a counter but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: The indentation isn't formatted.

Comment: All the input read functions I know about use Enter key to know the input is complete.  Ex. if you associate the numbers 1 through 5 to your shapes, you enter that number and press Enter.  Counting the number of Enters is "dangerous".  What delay between each Enter is considered the same series VS a new series?  3 Enters could be 1, then 2.  Or 2, then 1, ...  I feel you are making it more difficult for yourself that it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless ways to implement this sort of event handler.

One of them would be to create a class or namespace that keeps track of the different functions calls that draw the shapes and also has a variable that increases by 1 every time the enter button is pressed.  Then in the `onkey` callback, create a new function that reads the key count and matches it up with the corresponding function from the namespace and calls that function.

For Example:

```
import turtle

def draw_triangle():
    turtle.color('black')
    draw_line_turn()
    draw_line_turn()
    draw_line_turn()

def draw_line_turn():
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.up()

def draw_square():   # I just created this as an example
    turtle.up()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(120)
    turtle.down()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(240)

class EnterKey:
    """
    This is a simple namespace class that will keep track of our
    different shape functions and the number of times the enter
    key is pressed.
    """
    count = 0   # Number of times the Enter key has been pressed
    funcs = {   # <- shape functions
        1: draw_triangle, # to change the order they called just change the key
        2: draw_square,
       #3: draw_cirlce,   <- continue to add functions when you make new shapes
    }

def triangle_sequence1():
    turtle.clear()
    draw_triangle()

def draw_ts1():
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(handle, "Return")

def handle(): # this is the handler that calls the shape functions
    EnterKey.times += 1   # <- Increase the number of times enter has been pressed
    EnterKey.funcs[EnterKey.times]()  # <- call the corresponding function for
                                      # the newly increased number

draw_ts1()
turtle.done()
```